# Conv2d for image with additional features as input layer

Tags: keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I would like to train a model with Keras and TensorFlow.
My input consists of images and some additional features.
I would like to use conv2d for the images and dense for the other inputs.

The question is how do I build an architecure that has multiple input types where each one gets connected to a different layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do using the keras functional API. Assuming you have an image of size 28 by 28 and 5 additional features, your model could look something like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, concatenate

input_image = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
input_features = Input(shape=(5,))

# apply convolutional layers to image branch
x = Conv2D(32, 3)(input_image)
x = Conv2D(32, 3)(x)
x = MaxPool2D(2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)

# concatenate flattened image branch with input features
concat = concatenate([x, input_features])

# apply dense layers on concatenated data
dense = Dense(64)(concat)
output = Dense(64)(dense)

# create models using inputs and output specified above
model = Model(inputs=[input_image, input_features], outputs=output)
```

When visualized the model structure would like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras

keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]